# How do I add <blink> to reveal.js slides?

Tags: css, reveal.js

I am a total newbie, hope thats not too trivial:

How do I add  to reveal.js slides? I tried to add

```
blink, .blink {

  -webkit-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;

  -moz-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;

  -o-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;

  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;

}


@-webkit-keyframes blink {

  67% { opacity: 0 }

}


@-moz-keyframes blink {

  67% { opacity: 0 }

}


@-o-keyframes blink {

  67% { opacity: 0 }

}


@keyframes blink {

  67% { opacity: 0 }

}
```

to the css and then wrote:

```
<section>headline:
        <p class="fragment">text</p>
        <p class="fragment">text</p>
        <p class="fragment"><font color="FF1493"><blink>text that should blink in pink</blink></font></p>

</section>
```

but it didnt work.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for help,

Jean

Comment: Don't. Use. Blink. Ever. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink

Comment: I mean it..... Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<blink>` since it is [depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink)

```css
.blink {
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
  color: pink;
}

@keyframes blink {
  67% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<section>headline:
  <p class="fragment">text</p>
  <p class="fragment">text</p>
  <p class="fragment blink">text that should blink in pink </p>
</section>
```